# directional derivative, i dont understand the notation and how to do it

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Here's the initial function:
$$f(x,y,z) = 4x^3yz^2+2xz^3+xyz$$

Find the  directional derivative

$$f'\left ( \left ( \frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{-2}{3} \right ),\left ( 1,-1,-1 \right ) \right )$$ 
at the point $\left ( 1,-1,-1 \right)$ in the direction $\left ( \frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{-2}{3} \right )$

What does the f' means? and how am I supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the definition of the directional derivative from your lecture/your textbook? You should start with that and if you don't understand it, please provide the definition in your question and explain which part of it gets you in trouble. If you feel the need to compare your definition, you can have a look at [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) definition with different notation for the directional derivative of a function $f$ along a vector $v$ at point $x$ - Wikipedia's "$\nabla_v f(x)$" should be your "$f'(v,x)$".

Comment: Here's what i did but i'm not sure i did it right.

$\sqrt{\left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^2+\left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )^2+\left ( \frac{-2}{3} \right )^2}$

then put the result under 1, so  the result is 3 and then

$\left ( -13 \right )3+\left ( 3 \right )-3+\left ( 13 \right )-3=-87$

is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directional derivative is defined as follows:
$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f(\mathbf{u}) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{u} + h\mathbf{v}) - f(\mathbf{u})}{h}$$

In your case, the directional derivative of $f$ on the direction $[\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, -\frac{2}{3}]$ can be computed by:
$$ \nabla_{\mathbf{v}} f(x, y, z) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{2}{3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$$
Just plug $[1, -1, 1]$ into $[x, y, z]$.

Comment: oh okay, my final answer should be $\frac{-49}{3}$ then. Thank you